# setting imageview order on screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

when i create an imageview within the xcode using this code :

```
UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:@"image.png"];

img.frame = CGRectMake(40, 40, 80, 80);
img.alpha = 0.25;
[self.view addSubview:img];
```

it will generate the image in the view, but what if i have like lets say 5 buttons on the screen that i added using IB and i want the image that i created in the xcode to be behind the buttons what should i do ?

is there a line of code to set the image to the back ?

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:img];
```

Comment: @meronix i just did , sorry about that,, didnt know i could do it by now :)

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @Noah you can use:

```
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:img];
```

to simply send your view to the back. You can also use the following for more advanced configurations.

```
[self.view insertSubview:img aboveSubview:otherSubView];
[self.view insertSubview:img belowSubview:otherSubView];
[self.view insertSubview:img atIndex:MYINDEXPATH];
[self.view exchangeSubviewAtIndex:MYINDEXPATH withSubviewAtIndex:ANOTHERINDEXPATH];
```

Details can be found in the [UIView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html).

Comment: @aLFaRSi If either of these answers helped you then please mark the one that helped you the most as correct.